# Add tinymce API Key in google app scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, tinymce

I had been trying to add TinyMCE in a Google App Scripts project. In order to do that I got an API key from TinyMCE and added domain http://script.google.com to the domain list for the key.

Then added the API key to using the code below -

```
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=API"></script>
```

But when I tried to call the TinyMCE in that project HTML file, I got an error saying that -

```
The domain is not supported by your API key. Please review your domain settings here.
```

[Snapshot of the error on the page for TinyMCE when page is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv56R.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a quick `console.log(window.location)` reveals that the hostname is something else. In my case it is **n-4fcnzkskmuesjcsczo67y2qkpk3vxmg4aionr6i-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com**

It could be a different hostname for you since I think any number of google servers could be serving your page.

So try adding **googleusercontent.com** to your API settings in TinyMCE.

Comment: I did as suggested but the issue still seems to be there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is with tinymce and not Apps Script. Try the answer provided in [this tinymce forum](https://community.tinymce.com/communityQuestion?id=90661000000IfaxAAC) which encountered the same error.

> If you tried to use your API key before you added these other domains
>   the key is likely cached on our servers.  The TTL is 4 hours so it may
>   just take some time for the other domains to be valid.
>
> We will be enhancing the domain registration/addition process to flush
>   the cache when you make changes in an upcoming release of our cloud
>   environment.

Comment: Thanks it helped to get me to the issue.