# Domain not registered notice for TinyMCE in Google script project, but have registered Google script domains in account

Tags: tinymce-5

For Google script project, I've followed answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733318/add-tinymce-api-key-in-google-app-scripts) and this [Tiny article](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/this-domain-is-not-registered-with-tiny-cloud/) but now a notice to review "your approved domains" is appearing. In my Tiny account domains, these are registered:

localhost
googleusercontent.com
script.google.com

This error is new.  The Tiny editor was working fine (in-line mode) in script input forms, but now this notice is given, even though the editor appears to be working (text can be entered and formatted). May this have to do with end of the initial 30-day free trial (with advanced editor features)?  Now just have the free-version features.

If wildcards can be used, should I enter *.googleusercontent.com as approved domain, as the project may be running on a subdomain of googleusercontent.com or are all subdomains automatically included?  I don't know if that subdomain changes over time or for different users.

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The referrer domain makes the call to Tiny's server, it has to be exact on the approved domains list else it'll be considered not whitelisted - if you aren't sure of the domain to add of course a wild card would be first thought but how about load up dev tools in chrome, go to your site, view the network traffic check the assets and request to the tiny's javascript, you can easily identify the referring domain in the request (I attached a quick snap I took so you can see it) - add that domain as it appears to your approved domains, reload your page and see if it's the referrer issue or some kind of other trial limitation or something; but doing the above will for sure identify your referrer so you can test.

[image: TinyMCE Request in Google Chrome Dev Tools]

Comment: Thank you for outlining this.  After working with the approved domains and adding the exact subdomain--without resolving the problem--I looked at the Tiny API Key and it is now different in the Tiny account than what was configured for the input form (!).  Correcting the key solved problem. I do not know how those would be different, unless the API key changes when the initial Tiny trial period ends.  Anyway, your response helped me change focus and solve the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: Very welcome! Glad you nailed it!